# Flask w/ Gunicorn and SCRIPT_NAME

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I am attempting to run my Flask application with Gunicorn and defining the environment variable script name in order to have the root have a prefix, like `http://localhost:5000/my-app`.

My SCRIPT_NAME environment variable is: `my-app`

I am able to get to the root page of the app fine with the added prefix but when I attempt to execute a route in the application like, `/my-app/execute`, I get the following error message in my terminal:

`Error handling request /execute`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share the code where you're setting the application and the route?